# Remove _id suffix from foreign key migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to add a foreign key to via migration. It works as expected, but it automatically adds `_id` to the end (the column name I want to reference doesn't include `_id`). How can I make it reference the column name as I give it?

Here is the migration

```
class ChangeRefOnMemberPresentations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :member_presentations, 'employee_number', foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
  end
end
```

Which results in both the reference column name and foreign key reference column being called `employee_number_id` in schema.rb

Answer (score 1):

The following worked by defining everything manually, but seems messy. If there is a better migration answer, I'll be happy to accept.

```
def change
  # column was added in another migration, but including for completness
  add_column :member_presentations, :employee_number, :bigint
  add_index :member_presentations, :employee_number, name: "index_member_presentations_on_employee_number"
  add_foreign_key :member_presentations, :users, column: "employee_number"
end
```